# Duplicate value exception in Set

Tags: java, collections

It is said that those structures which implement Set interface do not allow duplicate elements. I just want to know, what do they mean by duplicate? Duplicate in terms of the values? Or in terms of objects. for example, I can add two Integer object of same value. I can also add the same object twice. What do they mean by duplicate? When will it throw an exception?

Answer (score 5):

Duplicate means as explained in another post `a.equals(b)`, which implies `a.hashCode()==b.hashCode()`.
However, when you add duplicate element, there will be no exception, simply it won't be added twice.

Answer (score 2):

The definition of equality depends on the container.  *Usually* it's the .equals()/.hashCode() relationship, but there are some containers that use identity for equality.

Comment: Not exactly, the definition of equality is specified in the Set interface. "More formally, sets contain no pair of elements e1 and e2 such that e1.equals(e2), and at most one null element"

Comment: There's a thing floating around called IdentityHashSet, by analogy with java.util.IdentityHashMap -- about which the docs say "This class is not a general-purpose Map implementation! While this class implements the Map interface, it intentionally violates Map's general contract, which mandates the use of the equals method when comparing objects. This class is designed for use only in the rare cases wherein reference-equality semantics are required." Substitute Set for Map and you see where I am...

Comment: I'm very much aware of those collections; my point being mentioning implementations which "break" the Set contract isn't a good example. Since the OP's question explicitly mentions "Set interface", `equals()` is a more appropriate answer here. Of course, YMMV.

Answer (score 2):

In `java.util` Collections, duplicate means that `a.equals(b)` and that *should* imply that `a.hashcode()==b.hashcode()`

Comment: *Must* imply hashcode equality, as specified in Object.hashCode().

Comment: @EJP - Well, "must" in the sense that "if you don't do this, you'll be very sorry."

Comment: @Malvolio 'must' in the sense that that is what the specification of the method says.

Comment: @EJP - If there's nothing here to argue about, then why are you arguing?  *In fact*, there are classes, even in the Java system libraries, that break the contract you're depending on.

Comment: @Malvolio I'm not 'depending' on any 'contract'. I'm aware that not everything in the world complies. I'm just repeating what the Javadoc says. It says 'must'.

Answer (score 1):

As per the Javadocs; it means any two elements wherein `e1.equals(e2)` returns true are treated as duplicate elements. Different set implementations use different strategies for storing elements; `HashSet` makes use of the `hashCode` of objects whereas `TreeSet` relies on the natural ordering (`Comparable` interface) or a custom `Comparator`.

Answer (score 0):

Fiver and Alvin gave good answers because "aps" is saying that he can add two of the same integers and objects but not get any compiler error or runtime exception which is true.

If you add these objects like you say and then run some code like

```
System.out.println(theSetYouMade.size());
```

and then you will see that it did not add those duplicates you were talking of.

Comment: Hey i didn't mean anything like that really...I just said that there are two ways of adding duplicates...I didn't talk about whether they give compiler errors or not...anyway I got it...

Answer (score -2):

`obj1` is duplicate of `obj2` if `obj1.equals(obj2)` returns true. So as you can see, the definition of equal really depends on the implementation of equals.

You can write a set say, DistincObjectSet where duplicate means `obj1==obj2`

Another example is you can have EmployeeSet where duplicate means obj1.employeeNo == obj2.employeeNo, in this case you should overwrite the equals() method in Employee class to compare the employee numbers.

The design of the Set API says you you attempt to add duplicate element, the add() method should return false instead of throwing Exception.

Comment: so it will depend on the type of set, right? TreeSet or HashSet or some custom Set etc?

Comment: obj1.hashCode()==obj2.hashCode() does NOT imply obj1.equals(obj2)

Comment: "For HashSet two objects are equal if they have same hash code". This is incorrect. Two objects are equal if equals() returns true. Period.

Comment: @EJP, yea that statement was false from me. Thanks for pointing that out. I have modified my answer accordingly

Comment: @EJP and how is .equals() implemented in HashSet? i mean how are custom objects compared in any set?

Comment: @aps, For HashSet, first, hash value is obtained from the obj. Then the bucket associated with that hash value is retrieved. Then the obj is compare with each of the object in that bucket by using equals() method.

Comment: @aps equals isn't implemented in HashSet, at least not in the way you mean. It *calls* equals() on the contained objects.

Comment: @Alvin OK now remove the first 'usually' and I will de-downvote. Object equality is *defined* by the equals() method. There's no 'usually' about it.

Comment: @EJP, fine in this context I agree with you :)

Comment: @aps take a look at http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/util/HashSet.java.html this is how HashSet is implemented. Take carefully look at contains() and add() methods. Also, if you want to dig deeper, take a look at how HashMap is implemented since HashSet uses HashMap to achieve uniqueness.

Comment: Well i'm sorry but I'm getting too confused...ok let's see...equals is the method which gives the definition of equality, right? that is, it states under what circumstances two objects will be said to be equal...that's why it can be overridden by different classes in different ways according to what the programmer wants equality to mean for two objects of that class...right? Please tell me if I'm wrong... But now I want to know, what the programmers of the class TreeSet meant by equality?or for that matter any Set...

Comment: @Alvin the statement is true in any context, not just this one. It is mandated by the specification I cited.

Comment: @aps What those programmers meant by equality is the result of the equals() method. There is nothing here to be confused about.